# Why struct definition is not included in the dump?

Tags: c++, linux, symbols

I created a simple program to learn how to get the symbol table from a shared library.

When I run `objdump -TC test` I don't see my `MyStruct` defined in the output. What am I missing here?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
    
struct MyStruct
{
    int i;
};
    
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MyStruct s;
    s.i = 1;
    std::cout << s.i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/home/.../test:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_atexit
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::ios_base::Init::Init()
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::ostream::operator<<(int)
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __libc_start_main
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              __gmon_start__
0000000000000000  w   D  *UND*  0000000000000000              _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
0000000000000000  w   DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 __cxa_finalize
0000000000004040 g    DO .bss   0000000000000110  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::cout
```

Comment: It's not a function, it has no constructor or destructor or functions, so why would it get dumped as a symbol? Those are really for code, like functions and other important features. Consider adding a constructor, or comparing vs. `class MyClass`.

Comment: Remember that C++ has absolutely no reflection capability so once compiled it's got no idea what's actually in a struct or class. It's all baked in to how the executable is written. The structure definition is just used to guide how to compile the code, and that often gets significantly altered by optimizing passes. Here the compiler might well ignore the struct entirely as you are really just manipulating a single `int`.

Comment: @tadman, I tried changin `struct` with `class` and adding a constructor with a parameter, but I got the exact same output

Comment: Is the constructor for the class used?

Comment: Compiler optimisation.   The only output from the program is printing the value `1`.   As long as it achieves that, the implementation is free to eliminate all sorts of things (code, data structures, etc).   Since the compiler has complete visibility of your code and definitions of the structure, it can analyse the net effect, and omit anything its analysis deems is unneeded.

Comment: What would you expect to see?